# ESLint + TypeScript + Stricter if statements

Tags: typescript, eslint

I've currently discovered a very subtle bug in my TypeScript project:

```js
const makeDecision = (): Promise<boolean> => {
  return Promise.resolve(false);
};

const shouldDoIt = makeDecision(); // Oops! I forgot the await

if (shouldDoIt) {
  // do stuff
}
```

(I hand typed that just now, so there may be a mistake...)

In this particular example, I forgot the `await` keyword which caused `shouldDoIt` to be a `Promise`, rather than a `boolean`. So, it'll always be truthy in a `if`-statement. Because this is valid behavior for JavaScript, the TypeScript compiler doesn't complain a bit even though this was not my intention. Obviously, computers don't magically know my intention, but compilers can be very strict if need-be.

Is there a way to either configure ESLint or the TypeScript compiler to be more strict about if-statements to only allow `boolean`, rather than truthy types? Ideally, I'd love the compiler or ESLint to fail for statements like:

```js
if ("a string") {
}

if (null) {
}

if (someNumber) {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typescript-eslint rule `strict-boolean-expressions` does what you're looking for. Additionally, the `no-unnecessary-condition` rule would have caught your case too.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26775296)

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu answer updated to include the essential information.